# XML node selection in XSLT will only select value by node()

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an problem with selecting some XML nodes in my XSLT, and don't know whats wrong.

My XML files is as followed (shortend):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice version="5.3.1" xmlns="http://isdoc.cz/namespace/invoice">
  <DocumentType>1</DocumentType>
  <ID>FV1755</ID>
  <UUID>375053CE-3B81-4C48-9492-C18503F1F203</UUID>
  <IssuingSystem>K2</IssuingSystem>
  <IssueDate>2014-03-31</IssueDate>
  <TaxPointDate>2014-03-31</TaxPointDate>
  ....
</Invoice>
```

My XSLT document is as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:pie  = "http://isdoc.cz/namespace/invoice"
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
   exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/pie:Invoice">
    <Invoice>
      <Id>
        <xsl:value-of select ="ID"/>
      </Id>
    </Invoice>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My result is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pie="http://isdoc.cz/namespace/invoice">
  <Id></Id>
</Invoice>
```

And here is the problem. Why can't i select the `<ID>`value, it is always empty no mater what i try.

The only way I can select the value is to direct address the XSLT to:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="node()[2]"/>
```

**How do I select the `<ID>` element in the XSLT?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to specify the namespace of `ID`:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="pie:ID"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot KJ, I was absolutely blinded.